# What is the correct way to handle ServiceHostFactory.CreateServiceHost failures?

Tags: wcf, service, servicehost

I have some WCF services that have been testing out just fine for some time now. We host them in IIS with Windows Process Activation Services (WAS). When the clients connect, the services crank up, and we're happy.

Now, paranoid as I am, before we ship this thing I wanted to test a range of edge cases related to how the services handle certain types of failure. One of the experiments involves a failure during the creation of the ServiceHost itself for a particular service.

We have a custom ServiceHostFactory (derived from ServiceHostFactoryBase) that does some initialization work and returns a fully configured service host. I'm simulating a configuration error which would cause CreateServiceHost to throw a ServiceActivationException during initialization. We also log the exception.

[As an aside, when our clients see this exception, they stop trying to access the service (on the assumption that if it failed to activate the first time, a human will need to get involved). This is different from, for example, an EndpointNotFoundException, where the client will keep trying periodically, assuming a transient network condition.]

What we see is that the client tries (once) to open a channel to the service. The ServiceHostFactory appears to try many times over the course of a few seconds to activate the service, each attempt fails with the expected exception message, and then the application pool appears to simply lock up. Calls to other services running inside that app pool (that have successfully activated) hang forever.

That seems odd. I don't mind that the failing service would get booted from the app pool after several failed attempts to activate it, but to kill other services seems wrong. Note that the app pool doesn't recycle, or stop -- it simply sits there not responding to requests to any service operation.

Is there something else I should be doing to tell WCF that a failure to activate one service should render that service "offline" but allow other services in the app pool to continue to process requests? Or am I missing something more fundamental with WAS?

Comment: Maybe not the answer you're looking for, but what about running each service in its own App Pool, that way they're isolated from issues in other services.  Might run into a resource issue if you have a ton of very active services, but if it's only a handful might be worth thinking about.

Comment: We could certainly do that, but a) we have a lot of services, b) we're a vendor, packaging this as a product, so we want to keep the configuration as simple as possible for customers, c) I'd really like to understand what's happening to cause this - I feel like I'm missing something fundamental.